# How to present modal view controller with transparent background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I working with swift and how to how to present modal view controller but his background to be transparent. Content of other view controller to be visible in back.

Comment: It would be better if you search for similar questions before posting new one

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me :

```
self.presentingViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.presentingViewController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```